# subgroup of locally compact group compactly generated

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a locally compact group, compactly generated, is it true that every closed subgroup of G is also compactly generated?

Comment: you should add topological-groups to your tags

Comment: If $G$ is abelian then it is true see http://pages.uoregon.edu/math/people/ross/subgroupsofCGLCA7.pdf

Comment: Think about discrete groups: Is it true that every subgroup of a finitely generated group is also finitely generated?

Answer (score 0):

It is false, I found a countrexample in the book Geometric Group Theory, by 
Cornelia Druµu and Michael Kapovich, there is two countrexamples in pages 197 and 198.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's even false if $G$ is discrete, e.g. the free group $F_2$ on 2 generators admits $F_\infty$ as a subgroup. Morale: for any general question on locally compact group, check about the discrete case.

It is also false when $G$ is a connected Lie group, since $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ admits $F_\infty$ as a closed subgroup.